# Android JUnit Test does not work

Tags: android, testing, junit

i am new on Android JUnit Testing and i am trying to to my StartActivity. But even simplest test does not work:

```
public class testMain extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {

     private MainActivity activity;
    private int buttonId;


    public testMain() {
            super(MainActivity.class);
          }


     @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent, null, null);
            activity = getActivity();
    }

     public void testOverViewButton() {

            try {
                /*
                buttonId = com.example.myexpenses.R.id.btnOverview;
                assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(buttonId));
                Button view = (Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
                assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "Übersicht",
                        view.getText());
                        */
                final String  hallo = "HalloWelt";
                assertEquals("HalloWelt", hallo); //Assert fails, and code
                                                  //above this, fails too                       
            } catch (Exception e) {
                fail();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
          }

}
```

My LogCat-File looks like this:

```
02-19 17:29:50.270: E/memtrack(2410): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-19 17:29:50.270: E/android.os.Debug(2410): failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-19 17:29:50.298: E/art(2410): Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
02-19 17:29:50.679: E/memtrack(2420): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-19 17:29:50.679: E/android.os.Debug(2420): failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-19 17:29:50.737: E/art(2420): Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
02-19 17:29:51.211: E/memtrack(2430): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-19 17:29:51.211: E/android.os.Debug(2430): failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-19 17:29:51.304: E/libprocessgroup(2441): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10045: Read-only file system
02-19 17:29:52.430: E/memtrack(2457): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-19 17:29:52.430: E/android.os.Debug(2457): failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-19 17:29:52.514: E/libprocessgroup(2468): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10045: Read-only file system
02-19 17:29:52.617: E/art(2468): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
```

How can i get more information??
Why is a assert Fail: 
final String  hallo = "HalloWelt";
assertEquals("HalloWelt", hallo);

Thx.

Comment: Take a look at Robolectric which works with JUnit. http://robolectric.org/

Comment: hey, thx you :)
that´s no a problem to test something, A problem is generally:
If i try:
Assert.assertTrue(1==1), it fails too